# link to open a new tab gets invisible in dashboard in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In r shiny i have added a help link to a pdf file which open on a new browser on click. On left is the logo and right is that link. On running the app,the logo on left is clearly visible but the help link is invisible.But when the cursor is hover around in that location on right in the browser it is visible in fade colour. However if the browser is restore down the link gets visible clearly.

Below is the ui code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "flex_logo",
         tags$li(class = "dropdown",
         tags$p(h4(a("Help",target="_blank",href="Flex-Forecasting_Usage_Guidelines.pdf"),
         style="font-weight: bold;color:red;")))
),
dashboardSidebar(
radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type",choices=c("csv file","xlsx file")) 
 ),
dashboardBody()
)
```

Here is server code

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
})
```

I want the link to be clearly visible all the time. I might be doing something which is very basic.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example? And also why do you wrap h4 in a h1 tag? Also can you get rid of the style before it's working?

Comment: ^Thanks for reply.I have added  Minimal working example. h1 has been replaced with p and for a change different color option has been tried but all gets invisible on maximising the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `color:red` doesn't get applied to your anchor `a` tag!

Modified Code:

```
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "flex_logo",
         tags$li(class = "dropdown",
         tags$a("Help",target="_blank",href="Flex-Forecasting_Usage_Guidelines.pdf",
         style="font-weight: bold;color:red;"))
),
dashboardSidebar(
radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type",choices=c("csv file","xlsx file"))
 ),
dashboardBody()
)
```

Comment: Glad, that helped. Please upvote and mark it an answer for others to know it helped!